# Click button(s) copy to clipboard using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a situation where a user need to copy (click copy-to-clipboard icon) a link, however I've multiple dynamic links on a single page.

I've found the solution on the following post but I don't know a way to pass clicked icon ID to function as parameter and get the link copied to clipboard.

[Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

```
<a href="sourcefile.php"><i class="fa fa-link pull-right" id"copyToClipboard1"></i></a>
<a href="anotherfile.php"><i class="fa fa-link pull-right" id"copyToClipboard2"></i></a>
<a href="someimageURL"><i class="fa fa-link pull-right" id"copyToClipboard3"></i></a>
```

I went through the following post here in order to pass element ids to the function but no use as I just started crawling on jQuery path.

[jQuery passing element ID into jquery statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499806/jquery-passing-element-id-into-jquery-statement)

Thanks in advance.

I don't have enough rep point therefore posting a new question [duplicate].

Comment: I think this is not possible, you need to select the text before copy it. The text of your link is not selectable. [`document.execCommand('copy')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: Hi, I see your point, If I add text in between anchor tags `code`<a href="sourcefile.php">sourcefile.php</a><i class="fa fa-link pull-right" id"copyToClipboard1"></i>, will that be any use. thanks

Comment: Not sure, I think you need to put it into an input or maybe a div with contenteditable.